# Creating a String Data Stucture

Tags: c++, arrays, string, class, data-structures

I am extremely confused about my String class assignment. I'm basically making a string data structure but without using the `string data type`. It takes three data members: value, length, and capacity. I made those.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Str {
    private:
    int length;
    int capacity;
    char* value;
```

Also there is suppose to be 8 class methods: grow, min, difference, getCharArrSize, copy, concatenate, compare, and print. 
I was given grow, min, difference, and GetCharArrSize. they look like this

```
void grow() {
    char *temp = value;
    capacity *= 2;
    value = new char[capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        value[i] = temp[i];
    }
}

int min(int a, int b) {
    if (a < b) return a;
    else return b;
}

int diffrence(int a, int b) {
    int d = 0;
    if (a > b) d = a - b;
    else if (b > a) d = b - a;
    return d;
}

int getCharArrSize(char *v) {
    int c = 0;
    while (v[c] != '\0') {
        c++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

now the instructions say grow is used in copy and concatenate. how would that work? the instructions for copy is: Overwrites the data of the string
array with the data contained in s.
and for concatenate is: Appends the data inside s onto the
data stored in the string. 
Also I'm doing all this in the header file. the test file looks like this:

```
#pragma once
#include "NewString.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Str s1("Hello ");
    Str s2("World");
    Str s3(", My ");
    Str s4("Name ");
    Str s5("is ");
    Str s6("Chad!");
    cout << s1.size() << endl;
    Str s7;
    s7.copy(s1);
    s7.concatenate(s2);
    s7.concatenate(s3);
    s7.concatenate(s4);
    s7.concatenate(s5);
    s7.concatenate(s6);*/
    s7.print();
    cout << "\n\n";
    Str s8("Hello World, My Name is Chad!");
    if (s8.compare(s7) == 0) {
        cout << "They Match!" << endl;
    }
    Str s9("I dont match....");
    if (s9.compare(s8) != 0) {
        cout << "I differ by " << s9.compare(s8) << " characters..." <<
            endl;*/
    }
}
```

I am very confused and have no idea how to proceed. 
Kindly help me on this.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Whoever gave you `grow` forgot to free memory

Answer (score 1):

So let's start by taking a look at what grow() does:

```
void grow() {
    char *temp = value; 
    capacity *= 2;
    value = new char[capacity]; // Double capacity
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        value[i] = temp[i]; // Copy all data from temp into value
    }
}
```

So, for example, if temp was `['a', 'b', 'c']` before, it will now be `['a', 'b', 'c', '', '', '']`. Make sense?

Now the question is: how can that help us with copy and concatenate? 
Let's start with copy. We need to be able to copy the string in the argument into the string calling the method. For example, after calling `str1.copy(str2)`, `str1` should be the same as `str2`. But here's the problem: what if `str2`'s capacity is greater than `str1`'s capacity? We can't simply copy the contents of `str2` into `str1` because they won't fit. So: we use our `grow()` method until it's big enough.

```
void copy(const Str& other) {
    // Grow buffer
    while (this.capacity < other.capacity) {
        this.grow();
    }

    // Copy contents of other
    for (int charIndex = 0; charIndex < other.capacity; charIndex++) {
        this.value[charIndex] = other.value[charIndex]
    }
}
```

Now, we can easily extend this knowledge to `concatenate`: we want to add `str2` to `str1`, but `str1` is not big enough yet. To solve this, we call `grow()` until we're greater than or equal to `str1.capacity + str2.capacity`, and then copy the contents of `str2` to the end of `str1`.

Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Is the 'this' part of the this.capacity what I should use or is it alluding to another variable already called in my program?